# Subqueries for group counts in SELECT statement using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**What I have and what I want to do**

I am using Microsoft SQL Server. Here is the first table (`tbl1`):

| ID | Var | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| # | # | # |
| ... |  |  |

And this is what `tbl2` looks like

| Var | Var3 |
| --- | --- |
| # | # |
| ... |  |

In both cases, `Var` is the unique key.

I would like to count all of the rows in tbl2 that correspond to a Var where tbl1.Var2 = 80. And I want this grouped by the ID column. So something that looks like this:

| ID | TheCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

I am trying to do this without a join because I am trying to understand how subqueries work for calculation.  Once I understand this, I want to add counts form other tables.  Eventually I want something of the form

```
select ID,
  (select count from another table with similar where clause as above)
  (select count from yet another table with similar clause as above)
  (select count from yet another table with similar clause as above)
from first table
```

| ID | TheCount | Another Count | More Counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | # | # |
| 2 | 2 | # | # |
| 3 | 4 | # | # |

**What I tried and what I got**

This works, but I get an ungrouped table (see below). Any time I uncomment a line trying to group by the ID, I get an error.

```
select 
    tbl1.ID,
    (select count(*)  
     from tbl2
     -- group by tbl1.ID
     where tbl2.Var = tbl1.Var
     -- group by tbl1.ID
    ) as TheCount
from 
    firstTable as tbl1
-- group by tbl1.ID
where 
    tbl1.Var2 = 80 
-- group by tbl1.ID
order by 
    tbl1.ID
```

Result:

| ID | TheCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

**Questions**

I know I can do this with a join. I really want to understand how subqueries for calculation work, so I can use them in other situations.  Any help is appreciated.

1. Any advice on how to accomplish this?
2. What about the code ensures that ID and TheCount are lined up properly? I did a partial inspection of the output, and it seems correct. It is confusing because ID doesn't appear anywhere in the subquery.
3. Why would one choose a subquery vs a join for something like this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "Group by" is the set of columns whose value will always be grouped together.

Therefore in the expected output, if you need it grouped by the id then the values in id column will be unique. The expected output cannot possibly be like this.

```
ID  TheCount
1   4
1   2
1   4
```

It would be

```
ID  TheCount
1   4
2   2
3   4
```

To get to this, you would group by the id field and apply a where condition to look for entires that have var field in tbl1 having a presence in tbl2.

```
select a.id,count(*)
  from tbl1 a
where a.var in (select b.var
                  from tbl2 b)
group by a.id
```

**Update**

A better option instead many "select in a select" would be to join

```
select a.id
       ,count(b.var) as cnt_in_tbl2
       ,count(c.col1) as cnt_in_tbl3
  from tbl1 a
```

left join tbl2 b
on a.var=b.var
left join tbl3 c
on a.col1=b.col1
group by a.id

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  It worked on the single count.  This is a trimmed down version of what I'm trying to do.  Eventually I want something where I get counts from multiple talbes.  I updated the original post to reflect that.